# R shiny rendertable - how to change column width to wrap text for specific column?

Tags: r, uitableview, html-table, shinydashboard

I am trying to display a table and a plot side by side. In my external screen which is wide enough, I can see all the table columns but on my laptop screen the table columns get overlapped by the plot. I have tried the tag heads and different combination of width values for that table but nothing is working. If I could only wrap the first column into two lines then I think that should solve the problem.

How do I change column width just the first column so that the column gets word wrapped?

[image]

UI

```
br(),
                hr(style = "border-color: black;"),
                fluidRow(
                    column(6, tableOutput("pdl1_combo_tbl")),
                    column(6, plotlyOutput("pdl1_combo_plot", height = 'auto', width = 'auto'))
                )
                
                
            )
```

Server Output table

```
output$pdl1_combo_tbl <- renderTable(
        rbind(filtData_pdl1_combo() %>% 
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% select_if(not_all_na) ,
              filtData_pdl1_combo() %>%
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% 
                  select_if(not_all_na) %>% 
                  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                  mutate(line_name = "Total")) %>% 
            replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
            rename("PD-1/PD-L1 + chemo combos (incl. nivo+ipi)" = line_name) %>% 
            select(-contains("NA")),
        spacing = c("xs"), striped = TRUE, width = '35%'
    )
```

html

```
 <div id="pdl1_combo_tbl" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite"><table class="table shiny-table table-striped spacing-xs" style="width:auto;">
    <thead> <tr> <th style="text-align: left;"> PD-1/PD-L1 + chemo combos (incl. nivo+ipi) </th> <th style="text-align: right;"> Jul 2020 </th> <th style="text-align: right;"> Aug 2020 </th> <th style="text-align: right;"> Sep 2020 </th> <th style="text-align: right;"> Oct 2020 </th> <th style="text-align: right;"> Nov 2020 </th> <th style="text-align: right;"> Dec 2020 </th>  </tr> </thead> <tbody>
      <tr> <td> atezolizumab,bevacizumab,carboplatin,paclitaxel </td> <td align="right">   3 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> atezolizumab,carboplatin,paclitaxel protein-bound </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> <td align="right">   4 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> <td align="right">   7 </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> carboplatin,paclitaxel,pembrolizumab </td> <td align="right">  20 </td> <td align="right">  28 </td> <td align="right">  16 </td> <td align="right">  22 </td> <td align="right">  32 </td> <td align="right">  15 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> carboplatin,pembrolizumab,pemetrexed </td> <td align="right">  89 </td> <td align="right">  73 </td> <td align="right">  76 </td> <td align="right">  68 </td> <td align="right">  68 </td> <td align="right">  68 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> ipilimumab,nivolumab </td> <td align="right">   7 </td> <td align="right">   7 </td> <td align="right">  15 </td> <td align="right">   3 </td> <td align="right">  13 </td> <td align="right">  16 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> pembrolizumab,pemetrexed </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> atezolizumab,carboplatin,paclitaxel </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> carboplatin,paclitaxel protein-Bound,pembrolizumab </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> atezolizumab,bevacizumab,carboplatin,paclitaxel protein-bound </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> <td align="right">   0 </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> Total </td> <td align="right"> 122 </td> <td align="right"> 113 </td> <td align="right"> 111 </td> <td align="right"> 101 </td> <td align="right"> 119 </td> <td align="right"> 105 </td> </tr>
       </tbody> </table></div>
```

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out?